# Jquery Date.parse is returning NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, datetime-format

I'm trying to parse a value from an input type=datetime-local using Jquery. I do know why, but it s returning me a NaN when I tell it to parse a variable.

```
$("#new-broadcast-arrival-time").on("change", function(){
    var a = $(this).val();
    var d = Date.parse(a);
    console.log(a);
    console.log(d);
})
```

and my output is

> 123213-03-12T12:12
>
> NaN

What is wrong ?

2) My expectation output is
**yyyymmddhhmmss**

How can I have this ?

Comment: Date is probably out of range. The year is "123213"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, the given date is invalid.

So to answer your question if you want the output to be: yyyymmddhhmmss

You have to use [dateFormat](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format)

example code with dateFormat:

```
var a = $(this).val();
var dateFormat = require('dateformat');
var yourdate = new Date(a);
dateFormat(yourdate, "yyyy mm dd hh:mm:ss");
```

An other possible way would be to use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) which is a complete library that can format dates and do alot of stuff with them. You can take a look at their doc it is fully detailed.

**EDIT:**

If using a library really bothers you, here is how you could do it without one. (Dirty but works...)

```
 var str = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate() + " " +  date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds();
```

Comment: is there a way of doing this without a plugin ?

Answer (score 4):

That's probably because `123213-03-12T12:12` is not a valid date format. `Date.parse()` will return `NaN` if it does not recognize a date string or if it is an invalid date. In your case, it seems like it is an invalid date format.

Here is an [excerpt from the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse):

> ... `NaN` if the string is **unrecognised** or, in some cases, contains **illegal date** values (e.g. 2015-02-31).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `Date.parse`. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse):

> It is not recommended to use `Date.parse` as until ES5, parsing of strings was entirely implementation dependent. There are still many differences in how different hosts parse date strings, therefore date strings should be manually parsed (a library can help if many different formats are to be accommodated).

In your case it's returning `NaN`, because it's out of range — the year is `123213`.

I recommend you using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library instead.